# .htaccess execute file from different location

Tags: .htaccess

I've got a URL structure where there's a gallery page at /worcester/gallery which has an index.php file within. What I want is to have all child URLs of this, like /worcester/gallery/last-night to run the index.php file within /worcester/gallery.

I'm not looking to redirect the URL, I want to keep the URL as it is, I'll be using that to work out which gallery to get from index.php

Comment: How would `index.php` know which gallery was accessed?

Comment: It would do that by looking at the $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] to get the URL and that would set what gallery is being displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to access the URI in php, you can simply put the following as `.htaccess` inside `gallery/` directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule !^index\.php index.php [L]
```

I am not sure though, that `REQUEST_URI` will be available inside the `index.php` file. If it is, well and good; if it isn't, you can pass the rest of the URL as a GET parameter:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^((?!index\.php).+)$ index.php?uri=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was attempting something similar before but not in the /gallery directory, I was attempting to do it from the site root.

Also for anyone interested REQUEST_URI seems to be available with your method.